# CSS Column Overlap everywhere BUT IE and Firefox 3

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a problem with my website and how it appears in some browsers:

> http://www.karentiede.com

In Firefox 2.0 and many other browsers, the "content" column overflows to the left and appears on top of the decorative border, making some of the content unreadable.

One Q&A in here suggested that making all the pages `HTML 4.01 Strict DOCTYPE` might help make all browsers work the same, but that question was the reverse-worked in Firefox and didn't work in IE.  Is there another/different fix I should try?

From the CSS:

```
.column2 {
    float: right;
width: 80%;
}
```

From any of the pages that act up:

```
<body id="schedule_toc">
<div id="col1_schedule_toc">
<div class="column2">
```

When I check the site in http://www.browsershots.org, it looks bad on initial display in a lot of the browsers. I've had one or three (probably Firefox) readers tell me they couldn't see the text and I suspect they were probably more sophisticated users than I am a CSS-writer.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the page and the problem only appears when you re-size the page.

The problem is your right div is 80% so when the screen becomes smaller and ratios change and that 80% then overlaps into your left background.

Take a look at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/ to see how to set up a "static-fluid" layout.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening, it seems, is because the image (floated left) isn't the height of the entire page.  So, when the page isn't wide enough to accommodate both the image and the text next to each other, the text breaks to the next available whitespace.

Try floating **both** elements to the left, and apply a left-margin equal to the width of the "decorative" column to column2 as such:

```
.column1 { float: left; width: 125px; }
.column2 { float: left; margin-left: 125px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

You'll need a clearing div below both elements:

```
<div class="column1">...</div>
<div class="column2">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Small typo, but great advice (that crossed mine, thus I didn't reference it). Uprated.

Comment: Your suggested fix will definitely work, but I don't think it's the image that's the problem - it would be if the main col wasn't floated right, but it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is definitely ratios, as pointed out by *savageguy*. If what you are wanting is a fixed-width left column with a variable width right (main) column then you could use this (not tested but should work):

```
#col1_schedule_toc {
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
}

.column2 {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Incidentally, I noticed that (at least on the page I looked at) you also aren't closing the left column before you open the right, so technically the right column is inside the left, which will cause issues with my suggested fix. So you also need to move the closing *div* for col 1 so that it's above the opening *div* for col 2.

EDIT 2: Plus, as pointed out by *Plan B*, you'll also need a clearing div beneath both elements to prevent the parent (container) div from collapsing:

```
div.clear {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to savageguy's right-on-point advice, the image you have in the page (your picture, etc.) to the left is a fixed width. This is why, when the browser is re-sized, that 80% suddenly becomes too wide.

On column2, setting a left margin of the width of the image + the amount of separation you want (for example, 160 should work, but you can play with it), then making the width of the column2 100% (of the remaining width) should prevent your overlap.

[Edit: Plan B also offers a very robust solution.)